# Django Contact Form Mail Error

Tags: django, forms, email

My form sends the email from the account listed in my settings.py fine, but in the message I only get the subject part of the form and the message part. There is no sender part within the email, so I can't tell who would be sending the email. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
```

My Views.py contact function

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        recipients = ['otheremail@gmail.com']
        send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

else:
    form = ContactForm()
return render(request, "contact.html", {'form':form,})
```

My Settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

Answer (score 0):

That code should work fine. I have implemented the same thing below and it works, but I had one issue with gmail that you might be having.

```
send_mail(Subject, Message, 'myemail@example.ca', To)
```

The issue was that in order to have the sender be the sender I assigned when using gmail in settings - the "sender" had to be in the approved senders list within your gmail account settings.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but the problem isnt actually the sending of the email. It's the fact that send_mail() only allows two fields to be sent: the Subject and the Message. However, my form has an option for people to list their personal email, which isn't allowed to be passed into the send_mail() function. Is there a way to add fields to send_mail()?

Comment: What other fields are you looking to add? For greater flexibility you may want to look at the EmailMessage class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#emailmessage-objects

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the EMAIL_HOST_USER as the sender because you are going to send the mail from this user account.
Please import your settings in your views.py as mentioned below.

```
import settings

send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipients)
```

Comment: You do not necessarily have to use EMAIL_HOST_USER as the sender. As long as the address is an approved sender in the gmail account settings it will work as well. I have an app the sends from multiple alternate accounts all through the same gmail connection settings.

Comment: You are correct that can be used, but over here instead of hardcoding the value on the send_mail() function it's better to use the variable you defined in the settings.py file. And also the form_email argument which has to be passed to the send_mail() function is always a string.